# sending data over networkstream goes wrong

Tags: c#, networking, stream, byte

I have the following code that sends data:
writer is a NetworkStreamWriter instance.
img is an Image instance.

```
writer.AutoFlush = true;
writer.WriteLine("picture");
BinaryWriter bWriter = new BinaryWriter(writer.BaseStream);
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
           img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
           byte[] buffer = new byte[ms.Length];
           ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
           ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
           bWriter.Write(buffer.Length);
           bWriter.Write(buffer);
           bWriter.Flush();
           ms.Flush();
```

then, on the client side, I have a receiving code:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string message = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                BinaryReader breader = new BinaryReader(stream);
                int ctBytes = breader.ReadInt32();
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(breader.ReadBytes(ctBytes));
                Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img, (int)System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth, (int)System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight);
                ShowImage(bmp);
                ms.Flush();
                breader.BaseStream.Flush();
```

the sending code runs every 40 miliseconds, and the receiving code runs inside a loop asynchronously (works when the "picture" string is sent)
but the receiving code works only for about 4 iterations, afterwards the ctBytes becomes negative and an exception is being throwed (you can't read a negative number of bytes).
I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: You cannot use StreamReader.  It has an internal buffer that causes too many bytes to be read from the stream.  There's no point, simply use BinaryReader/Writer to read and write the string as well.

Comment: but when I'm using writeline and readline shouldn't it shouldn't it write and read just one line?

Comment: and I can't read async with binary reader..